# Different rows in table but with same foreign key with MySQL and php

Tags: php, mysql

How to have different rows in table but with same foreign key, having the event as the same, but not inserting into event table again?

The `Event_ID` is consistent across `event` table and `participant` table but I need it to be the same for the same event in `participant` table and not to insert into `event` table for same event

this is my code snippet :

```
$whatsapp=mysql_query("SELECT $event_name FROM event");
$resultwhatsapp = mysql_query($whatsapp,$conn);
if(mysql_num_rows($resultwhatsapp) == 0)
{
  $sql1 = "INSERT INTO event VALUES('','".$event_name."',        '".$event_venue."', '".$event_date."', '".$event_sum."', '".$event_ran."', '".$event_ex."')";
  $result1 = mysql_query($sql1, $conn);
  $event_id = mysql_insert_id($conn);
  //mysql_free_result($result1);
}
//inserting into the participant table.
$qry = "INSERT INTO participant  VALUES('','$event_id','".$userTypeID."','".$full_name."','".$gender."','".$or    ganisation."','".$phone."','".$email."')";
$resultqry = mysql_query($qry, $conn);
//mysql_free_result($resultqry);

//$sql1 = "INSERT INTO event VALUES('','$part_id', '".$event_name."',  '".$event_venue."', '".$event_date."', '".$event_sum."', '".$event_ran."',  '".$event_ex."')";
//$result1 = mysql_query($sql1, $conn);
//mysql_free_result($result1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems ambiguous, but i am going to try and answer it in context....

So you have `EVENTS` and `PARTICIPANTS` and you want to know which participants are going for a certain event.

So your  might want to create a 3rd table call it `ATTENDEES` for each participant who registers for an event, insert the `event_id` and `participant_id` into the `ATTENDEES` table.

So if you want to know which participants are going for a certain event, you just look for all attendees in the `ATTENDEES` table where `EVENT_ID` for that event.

Also read on [many to many relations to get a better picture](http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/9922/~/understanding-and-creating-many-to-many-relationships-in-filemaker-pro)

Answer (score 0):

This seems a very good problem.

**Here's what you're doing:**

- You push data to the `event` table.
- You pick the `eventID` from the `event` table and use it to push other data to
  the `participant` table.

**Here's what you want to do:**

- Push data to `event` table.
- Push data to `participant` table with same `eventID` from the push to `event` table.
- Have that `eventID` remain the same in both `event` and `participant` tables for the same `event`.

**Here's how to do it:**

- Create a separate field in `event` table to store `eventID`. Alternatively, you can leave the current `eventID` for counting purposes, or remove `AUTOINCREMENT` from it's properties so you can take control of it. The aim of this step is to be able to manually manage your `eventID` variable.
- Declare [at least mentally] `eventID` numbers with their corresponding `events`. This way, you know what `eventID` represents what `event`, and vice-versa. This information will come in handy in the future.
- Create a [non `AUTOINCREMENT`] field in your participant table with `eventID`. This will be the foreign key from your event table.
- At every `INSERT INTO event` statement, use the eventID<->event matching you made at step 2 to manually push an `eventID` to the `event` table with the data you're pushing. This ensures that dance_event and run_event each have unique `eventID` values and dance_event and run_event will each have their `eventID` uniform across rows.
- At every `INSERT INTO participant` statement, repeat step 4 above and submit the `eventID` based on the eventID<->event matching you made at step 2. This ensures that you have the same `evendID` across participant rows that attended the same event.

Since the `eventID` is standard across the two tables, it can be used to query for events that a participant attended, as well as participants that attended a particular event.

**----ORRRRRR----**

You can go @TheSammie way and create a third 'buffer' table to help smooth things over.

**How it works:**

- Create a table, say, `attendees`.
- After every `INSERT INTO event` and `INSERT INTO participant`, do a `INSERT INTO attendees VALUES ( your_eventID , your_participantID )`

That's it! Shorter than the blubber at the top, and **still gets the job done!**

PS: In my past encounters with this issue, I've used @TheSammie's solution and it has worked like a charm!